# Laravel - How to Prevent users from auto-login in Laravel-Azure Socialite

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 Application, I made use of Azure AD Socialite Authentication:

LoginController

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
     $azureUser = Socialite::with('azure')->user();
    try 
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $azureUser->email)->orWhere('username', $azureUser->user['mailNickname'])->first();
        if($user)
        {
            if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id))
            {
                $user->update([
                     'last_login_at' => now(),
                ]);
               return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(\Exception $e) 
    {
        session()->flash("error", "Authentication failed, kindly contact the Administrator!");
        return redirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

login.blade

```
     <h2 class="login-box-msg"><b>Welcome</b></h2>

        @if(session()->has('error'))
           <p>{{ session()->get('error') }}</p>
        @endif
        <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">{{ trans('global.login') }}</button>-->
                    <a href="{{ route('azure.login') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

When the user clicks on Login, the application should redirect to Azure AD Login.  And then if the login is successful, it should redirect to Dashboard.

This happens at the first instance, but when the user wants to access  the application at other time, at the click of login it redirects him straight to the dashboard without AZ username and password.

But when I clear the browser cache, it requests for username and password.

How do I make the application at any instance to always request for Azure AD credentials?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
I am also looking for same solution. I want the user to provide login detail every time when ever user try to login with Azure account detail but i didn't find anything. were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
 return Socialite::with('azure')->with(["prompt" => "select_account"])->redirect();
}
```